# Why does my API call to OVH not work on my allocated ipBlock?

Tags: python, api, ansible, ip-address, ovh

## Problem

I'm been stuck on how to use this [OVH's call](https://api.ovh.com/console/#/ip/%7Bip%7D/task/%7BtaskId%7D#GET) call to obtain the MAC that has been assigned for the task. The problem is, I can't seem to successfully guess what the required "ip" parameter of type "ipBlock" is.

## My addressing

193.xx.x.115: My dedicated server running many containers
151.zz.z.192/27: The IP address block that we have purchased from OVH to assign a public IP address to each container
151.zz.z.219: An existing container that has recently had a vMAC allocation task complete (source of taskId)

## What I've tried to use with client.get(URL)

```
URL = "/ip/" + 151.zz.z.192/27 + "/task/" + taskID
```

throws `ovh.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundError: Got an invalid (or empty) URL`

```
URL = "/ip/" + 151.zz.z.192 + "/task/" + taskID
```

throws `ovh.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundError: The requested object (ip = 151.80.6.192) does not exist`

```
URL = "/ip/" + 151.zz.z.219 + "/task/" + taskID
```

throws `ovh.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundError: The requested object (ip = 151.80.6.211) does not exist`

```
URL = "/ip/" + 193.xx.x.115 + "/task/" + taskID
```

throws `ovh.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundError: The requested object (taskId = 127250060) does not exist`

## Overall

I am starting to wonder whether this API call works with vMACs at all. The only time it finds the URL and resource valid is when I point it directly at the dedicated server and not the IP block that's allocated for the containers or a CT address.

At the same time though, this seems less likely when we consider that I've successfully used [another API call](https://api.ovh.com/console/#/dedicated/server/%7BserviceName%7D/virtualMac#POST) just before that to assign a vMac to the same container IP address.

Is there any advice you can offer? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The valid format of ipBlock is the kind you get returned from the `/ip/` call. In your case: `151.zz.z.192/27`.

From my experiments, it does not look like the tasks under `/ip/...` include the vmac creation tasks. I tried creating several vmacs, and the associated tasks show up at: `/dedicated/server/{serviceName}/task` (`function=addVirtualMac`).

You can get the done status from there, (`/dedicated/server/{serviceName}/task/{taskId}`, specifically), but that does not include the generated MAC.

There is one endpoint that shows all virtual MACs. Maybe you can use that one for your purposes: `/dedicated/server/{serviceName}/virtualMac`

Comment: That's it, thank you! 
  
In short, the call I was using was actually for something entirely different, and the way to obtain the MAC address would be:
  
`/dedicated/server/{serviceName}/task` The one we need to extract a list of all the MACs for a serviceName  

`/dedicated/server/{serviceName}/task/{taskId}` : Lets us know if a task for a specific serviceName is done yet - halt execution until then  
`/dedicated/server/{serviceName}/virtualMac` : For each vMac, query the details per IP address, and once it matches, extract the MAC